# How to read root tag and root closing tag to a Perl variable?

Tags: xml, perl

I am new to Perl. I want to read the xml root tag and root end tag to a perl variable.

I tried this normal file reading. It worked. I am getting fist line and last line. But some times you can't trust the fist line if there is no new line. So done with a regular expression for reading the first line.

But I googled it for some built in Perl xml function to get this done. I did not find any, i.e all are new to me.

Please let me know which library is best for this. Some example if possible.

eg:-

```
<nst:root arg='1' arg2='2' arg3='3'>
   <a>1</a>
   <b>2</b>
</nst:root>
```

I want 2 variable like,

```
$root = '<nst:root arg='1' arg2='2' arg3='3'>';
$rootClose = '</nst:root>';
```

I want to replace this root tag with other xml. Please help.

This is what I wanted to do. I have a xml file and that has actual root tag. I split that file in to multiple using `XML::Twig::xml_split`. I get many files but header is different. I want to update the child file with actual header from main file

EG:-

Split limit is 2

Actual file is,

```
<nst:root arg='1' arg2='2' arg3='3'>
       <a>1</a>
       <a>1</a>
       <a>1</a>
       <a>1</a>
       <a>1</a>
       <a>1</a>
</nst:root>
```

It will split to, 3 files with `XML::Twig::xml_split`. And plugin add its own header.

```
File1:-
<xml_split:root xmlns:xml_split="http://xmltwig.com/xml_split">
           <a>1</a>
           <a>1</a>
</xml_split:root>

File2:-
<xml_split:root xmlns:xml_split="http://xmltwig.com/xml_split">
           <a>1</a>
           <a>1</a>
</xml_split:root>

File3:-
<xml_split:root xmlns:xml_split="http://xmltwig.com/xml_split">
           <a>1</a>
           <a>1</a>
</xml_split:root>
```

I want it like

```
File1:-
<nst:root arg='1' arg2='2' arg3='3'>
           <a>1</a>
           <a>1</a>
</nst:root>

File2:-
<nst:root arg='1' arg2='2' arg3='3'>
           <a>1</a>
           <a>1</a>
</nst:root>

File3:-
<nst:root arg='1' arg2='2' arg3='3'>
           <a>1</a>
           <a>1</a>
</nst:root>
```

Comment: @mirod can you help me in this ?

Comment: Why do you want the opening tag in one variable and the closing one in another variable? Where is declared that namespace ?

Comment: See this is what I wanted to do. I have a xml file and that has actual root tag. I split that file in to multiple using `XML::Twig::xml_split`. I get many files but header is different. I want to update the child file with actual header from main file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to use `xml_split` program, but here you have an approach using `XML::Twig` module, where I create new elements and move each pair of childs from one tree to another one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use POSIX qw<ceil>;

my ($split_limit, $n) = (2, 0); 

my $twig = XML::Twig->new->parsefile( shift );
my $root = $twig->root;

for (  1 .. ceil( $root->children_count / $split_limit ) ) { 
    my $t = XML::Twig::Elt->new( $root->tag, $root->atts );
    for ( 1 .. $split_limit ) { 
        my $children = $root->first_child;
        last unless $children;
        $children->move( last_child => $t );
    }   
    $t->print_to_file( 'xmlfile-' . $n++ . '.xml' );
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields one file for each pair of childs of root with its header:

```
==> xmlfile-0.xml <==
<nst:root arg="1" arg2="2" arg3="3"><a>1</a><a>1</a></nst:root>
==> xmlfile-1.xml <==
<nst:root arg="1" arg2="2" arg3="3"><a>1</a><a>1</a></nst:root>
==> xmlfile-2.xml <==
<nst:root arg="1" arg2="2" arg3="3"><a>1</a><a>1</a></nst:root>
```

Comment: I want the child xml file header should be replaced with original file. Not child element header

Comment: @Sahal: I don't understand you. Provide sample output data based in your input.

Comment: Please check the example part

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. One last help. I have 9 records in original file. It created 4 files (split_limit = 2) and it ignored last record. It should create 5 files last one should have one record. It takes to understand the code. For you it will be easy